# Client Side or Server Side to generate PAYFORT Token?

Tags: payment, payfort

I'm going to add PAYFORT integration `Hosted Installments` to my website 
and got confused in a point:
Should i generate the Token in the client side(js request) or server side (Python), what makes it confusing that i need to send `access_code` and `merchant_identifier` in the `TOKENIZATION` request

it's not mentioned in the docs that these keys are `confidential or not`

Could anyone please used this integration advice me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

merchant_identifier and access_code are not confidential, however tokenization only from client side :POST

Answer (score 0):

you can find the `merchant_identifier` and `access_code` in payfort admin panel when select `security setting`
and this is static in you application but with that you must send other information to success your process from client side like `merchant_reference` , `language` , `expiry_date` ,`card_number`, `card_security_code` to create `signature` and then send your request with `signature` to payfort api with all of these information

i hope help you with this explain